# sqlalchemy orm - get table definition from DB

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm

SQLAlchemy, Is there a way to create table definition class directly, beacause the table has already existed in DB, most documents tell me to make the definition mannually.

```
Base = declarative_base()

# ORM defininition
class Dep(Base):
    __tablename__='dep'
    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    dname=Column(String(64),nullable=False,index=True)

# Add new obs
session = sessionMaker()
row_obj=Dep(dname='saleman') 
session.add(row_obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are [several of ways to reflect tables in SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_tables.html#mapping-declaratively-with-reflected-tables).

I'll put here examples inspired by the documentation.

###### 1. Giving the class an [autoloaded `__table__`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#reflecting-database-objects)

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()  # same declarative_base() as usual

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydatabase.db")  # get your engine

class User(Base):
    __table__ = Table("user", Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine)
```

###### 2. Retrieving classes with the [Automap extension](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/automap.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.automap)

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

Base = automap_base()  # rather than declarative_base()

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydatabase.db")  # get your engine

Base.prepare(autoload_with=engine)  # reflect the tables and classes

User = Base.classes.user  # retrieve classes from table name
```

###### 3. Inheriting from the [`DeferredReflection` extension](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/declarative/index.html?highlight=deferred#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.DeferredReflection)

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeferredReflection
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()  # same declarative_base() as usual

class User(DeferredReflection, Base):  # define your class
    __tablename__ = "user"

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydatabase.db")  # get your engine

User.prepare(engine)  # reflect the table and attributes
```

The two first examples need an engine to create the class, which can be inconvenient for testing and such, so I prefer the third one which allows me to have class and engine defined in different places, but all three will work.