# How do I access a column that was added into a table (that was created by sqlalchemy) through the command line database utility in python?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

The table was already created using sqlalchemy.

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    mobile = db.Column(db.String(20))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    notification = db.Column(db.String(5))
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    superuser = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', admin='%s')>" % (
            self.name,
            self.admin
        )
```

Then I added a column through the command line mysql utility, now I want to access it through python. Is there a way to add it to the model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have a single location where your models's schema are defined (python SQLAlchemy + SQL script executed manually), then you'll need to reflect the tables/models from the database (which does have the full schema).

Reflecting can be done in [several of ways](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_tables.html#mapping-declaratively-with-reflected-tables),  I'll put here the simplest method ([autoloaded `__table__`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#reflecting-database-objects)) inspired by the documentation (see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72721402/17676984) for other examples).

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()  # same declarative_base() as usual

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydatabase.db")  # get your engine

class User(Base):
    __table__ = Table("user", Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine)
```