# How to update an item on a database table using SQLAlchemy (without the ORM Object)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I would like to update (or add/delete) an item from a Database Table using SQLAlchemy but the table has 1000+ columns and it wouldn't be feasible to create the ORM Object using the declarative_base procedure. Ideally, I would like to be able to extract the structure of the Item from the database and send a new one (or update, or delete).

I tried using the sqlalchemy.Table object, but it only allow me to read data from the database and doesn't allow for editting.

For example :

```
from datetime import date
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///FullDatabase.db')

meta = sa.MetaData(engine)
history = sa.Table('history', meta, autoload=True)
session = orm.Session(engine)

entry = session.query(history).where(history.c.Date == date(2023, 1, 25)).first()
```

With this I can extract the information, but I can't edit it the same way I could if I had the **History** object defined (but as I mentioned, there are 1000+ columns to map)

For example : (one of the columns is HousePrice)

```
entry.HousePrice = 100
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Is there a way to do this update ?
A similar solution will be used to add/delete new items as well, I'd assume.
Appreciate in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely reflect classes declaratively (see the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_tables.html#mapping-declaratively-with-reflected-tables) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72721402/17676984)).

And then you can update in the way you've described above (see my example below).

However I'd imagine that in your case the error is just that you're trying to access an attribute directly while you should be reaching through the `c` columns.

```py
entry.c.HousePrice = 100  # should work
```

---

Demo of reflecting a class.

Let's set up a simple table.

```py
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("/tmp/so.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE user (username VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY)")
cur.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?)",
    [("alice",), ("bob",), ("charlie",)],
)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

And then, reflect and update `alice` to `ALICE`.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table, create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base

engine = create_engine("sqlite:////tmp/so.db", future=True, echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __table__ = Table("user", Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    alice = session.scalars(select(User).filter(User.username == "alice")).first()
    alice.username = "ALICE"
    session.add(alice)
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    results = session.scalars(select(User)).all()
    print([r.username for r in results])  # ['ALICE', 'bob', 'charlie']
```

Comment: That's great! It worked. And now it's only missing how I can update multiple columns using that. How can I loop through different fields in the line ```alice.username = "ALICE"``` ? I can't use ```for field in fields : alice.field = ... ``` right?

Comment: I tried using ```alice.__dict__[field] = ...``` but SQLAlchemy does not detect changes like that. Do you know how I can do this ? Thank you