Using SQLAlchemy metadata to get info about actual database vs the definition
I want to use the Metadata object to get information about my definitions (i.e., my Model objects) as well as going out to the actual database.  But no matter what I try, it always uses the defined information and not what's in the database.
Here's what I have:
engine = create_engine('...')


class ModelBase(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


metadata = ModelBase.metadata

print(metadata.tables.keys())

Even if I delete tables from the database, it still prints the names of the tables as they are defined.
I have tried using metadata.reflect(bind=engine), but that doesn't seem to have any affect.   Are there two different metadata objects, or 2 different ways to create the object?
I want to be able to compare my definitions with what is in the actual database

Maybe this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72721402/25598148 will help you to solve your issue. Also I should note once you load you application it will load all the models, so to reflect the changes in db you will need to restart application or somehow redefine/reflect metadata.

Base.metadata will contain the table definitions as derived from the models registered with Base.
The database definitions may be obtained via reflection:
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine(url, echo=True)
db_metadata = sa.Metadata()
db_metadata.reflect(engine)

The inspection tooling may also be of value (for the mappings).
